# Office 365 Internet Explorer issues with ActiveX

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, activex, office365

I got a problem with Sharepoint on Office 365. I created a Sharepoint database solution for our company. But now it turns out that those Sharepoint tables require Internet Explorer 32 bit, as Sharepoint's table filters require ActiveX to be active.

Well, 64 bit Win 7 does contain programs X86\ and that's a 32bit version of Internet explorer I assume. However still browsing the Office 365 website, with that browser. Still shows the warning under my table solution:

> De standaardweergave van de lijst is actief omdat de browser geen ActiveX-besturingselementen ondersteunt.

which in English translates to something like :

> The defaultview of the list is active as your browser does not support ActiveX

I'm using the latest Internet Explorer 32 bits, it should work to see ActiveX content, but it doesn't; any ideas to make use of Sharepoint's Office 365 list tables?

I wonder how other people solve problems where Office 365 won't support activeX.

Comment: Have you try to install this component? [Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734) a time ago I have a similar issue and it got fixed installing this, you should try it

Answer (score 0):

could this be related to https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036/EN-US?wa=wsignin1.0#top which occured with Dec 9th Windows update?

Comment: Linking offsite without providing a summary is discouraged.  Please copy the relevant portion of the page that you believe may be helpful.